# How can I build an xpath that matches all div's in a page that do NOT have a certain class?

Tags: xpath

I unfortunately have to scrape a webpage, and I'm doing so via Google Docs.

The document looks like this:

```
<div class='search'>
 <div class='new'>
  <img src="product1.png" title="Product 1 - €2.40"/>
 </div>
 <div class='new dupe'> <!-- this one appears dimmed: there's a better offer -->
                        <!-- I don't want these in my results -->
  <img src="product1.png" title="Product 1 - €2.70"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

The current xPath looks like this:

```
//div[@class='search']//@title
```

How can I modify it? I could do

```
//div[@class='search']//div[not(@class='dupe')]//@title
```

...but that won't work because no item actually has the list of `class`es being exactly `'dupe'`.

Comment: Could you provide a full webpage. I have some experience with using XPATH.

Comment: @Kim I'd rather not[.](http://www.tf2wh.com/allitems.php "but here it is if you have to.")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/div[@class='search']/div[not(contains(@class, 'dupe')]//@title
```

I would try to avoid using `//` and be more specific:

```
/div[@class='search']/div[not(contains(@class, 'dupe')]/img/@title
```

Comment: +1. Note that this still doesn't return anything, but that's because there are no titles in the XML.

Comment: @newtower The actual markup is kind of too complicated to do that, but this worked. :)